# Type mismatch error while using VBA

Tags: vba

I'm using VBA and I have an error while running the attached code, it says Type mismatch.

Can someone help me where to find the mistake?
please

```
Private Sub List1_DblClick()        
    Dim val As String
    Dim val2 As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set GSBMconn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
        If List1.Selected(i) Then
            val = List1.List(i)

            Debug.Print (val)
            Set rs = Grid.DataSource

            rs.AddNew        

            Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=cmd\cmd.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="

            With Adodc1
                .RecordSource = "SELECT *" & _
                                "FROM StockLevel3 " & _
                                "WHERE ItemName = '" & val & "'; "
            End With

            Set Grid.DataSource = Adodc1

            Adodc1.Refresh
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question, format the code properly and add an actual question. Take a look at the [help] for more information.

Comment: i got type mismatch error whenever i add list item in datagrid

Comment: You need to have `Option Explicit` specified at the top, and every variable declared with an explicit type. What is `Adodc1`? A connection? A recordset?

Comment: when i select item from list to add in datagrid but it shows mismatch error

Comment: yes i have option explicit on the top of my code

Comment: adodc1 is a connection

Comment: its local db well i edit it

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you let us know on which line the error happens. Are you sure `adodc1` is in fact `ADODB.Connection`? Normally this name is assigned to the ADODC control.

Comment: Set rs = Grid.DataSource this line contain error and adodc1 is a component which i use to get data from db and show in the gridview

Comment: basically adodc control you are right sorry for your inconvenience

Comment: first time i select item from list to add in datagrid it will perfect working when i select another item to add in datagrid then it shows mismatch error